# how to calculate the pixels for a box model in css

Tags: html, css

im doing a css for beginners tutorial, and we are at the point where we are doing box models, currently, we are using a div (the wrapper)  that has a width of 1000px, and we are trying to get all of the content to fit inside of the box. my question is, how do we calculate or add the pixels of the content, so that it may be able to fit within the 1000px width [specifically the section part (this is given the id #main)and the aside(this is given the id #news)]? when I launch the code in the browser, the content fits perfectly (1000px exactly), however the math doesnt add up, this is the code:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
  }

  h1 {font: bold 20px Tahoma;}
  h2 {font: bold 14px Tahoma;}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {display:block;}

body {text-align:center;}

#wrapper {

border: 1px solid black;
width: 1000px;
margin: 20px auto; /*this makes the box equal from the left and right side 
of the page*/
text-align: left;

}

#first_header {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding:20px;
 }

#menu {background-color: blue;
color: white;}

#menu li{
display:inline-block; /* this aligns the text side by side*/
list-style: none; /*this removes the bullet points or whatever that the 
list-style the text came with*/
padding: 5px;
font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}

#main {
float:left;
width:660px;
margin: 30px; /*720px, 280 left*/
}

#news {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding:30px;
  background: #66CCCC;
}

#main_footer {
clear:both; /*removes the floating properties on both the left and right 
side, making the text back to its default position (block left)*/
  text-align: center;
 padding:20px;
  border-top: 2px solid green;
}

article {
  background-color: #FFFBCC;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding:20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

article footer {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content fits perfectly (1000px exactly). Here is the calculation.

```
#main -> width 660px + leftmargin 30px + rightmargin 30px = 720px total.
#news -> width 220px + leftmargin 0px + rightmargin 0px + leftpadding 30px + rightpadding 30px =  280px total.
```

`margin:20px 0px` is equal to `margin:20px 0px 20px 0px`. I hope you know the position start from top, right, bottom and left.

So finally 720px + 280px = 1000px. Hope you are clear now.